# paginations with different items amount per page in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, pagination, pagedlist

I have following controller for **Image 1** view

```
 public ActionResult Add_Product(int? page)
    {       

        Product_Type_DropDownListEn();
        Product_Category_DropDownListEn();
        Subsidary_DropDownListEn();            

        var model = new AddNewProduct
        {
            ListProductFields = db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField.ToList()
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

**Image 1**:

---

[image]

---

This is [View Page code](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/GGozb) for above controller

This is [model class](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/6L87p/model-class) for above view

I want to add server side pagination for this, that means getting a following kind view

**Image 2**:

---

[image]

---

For this server side pagination I'm following [this Tutorial](http://wp.sjkp.dk/asp-net-mvc5-easy-server-side-data-paging/) but in that tutorial He is use same amount items per each page , which is about 25.

But in my scenario `var model` getting data like below

[image]

Now those 15 ListProdcutFields loading to one page.

1. I want to restrict Product_ID, ProductTypeID, ProductCategoryID, Subsidary_ID to first page
2. Then from 15 of ListProdcutFields restrict one ListProdcutFields per one page

Just struggling with the optimum Linq query for this

```
     public ActionResult Add_Product(int? page)
            {

                Product_Type_DropDownListEn();
                Product_Category_DropDownListEn();
                Subsidary_DropDownListEn();


                int itemsPerPage = 1;
                int pageNumber = page ?? 1;

                List<AB_ProductTypeCategoryField> fieldlist = new List<AB_ProductTypeCategoryField>();

               for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                fieldlist.Add(new AB_ProductTypeCategoryField() { fieldlist = AB_ProductTypeCategoryField.NewGuid().ToString() });
                }

                return View(luckyGuids.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 1));
   }
```

Comment: You really should boil this down to the essentials. You have two links to large chunks of code and one to a tutorial. Reduce it to a minimal & working sample.

Comment: @GertArnold Actually I refer those resources(two links to large chunks of code) if someone request , My requirement is find out most suitable linq query here